# Sorting a file using fields with specific value

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Recently, I had to sort several files according to records' ID; the catch was that there can be several types of records, and in each of those the field I had to use for sorting is on a different position. The fields, however, are easily identifiable thanks to `key=value` structure. To show a simple sample of the general structure:

```
fieldA=valueA|fieldB=valueB|recordType=A|id=2|fieldC=valueC
fieldD=valueD|recordType=B|id=1|fieldE=valueE
fieldF=valueF|fieldG=valueG|fieldH=valueH|recordType=C|id=3
```

I came up with a pipeline as follows, which did the job:

```
awk -F'[|=]' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if($i ~ "id") {i++; print $i"?"$0} }}' tester.txt | sort -n | awk -F'?' '{print $2}'
```

In other words the algorithm is as follows:

1. Split the record by both field and key-value separators (`|` and `=`)
2. Iterate through the elements and search for the `id` key
3. Print the next element (value of `id` key), a separator, and the whole line
4. Sort numerically
5. Remove prepended identifier to preserve records' structure

Processing the sample gives the output:

```
fieldD=valueD|recordType=B|id=1|fieldE=valueE
fieldA=valueA|fieldB=valueB|recordType=A|id=2|fieldC=valueC
fieldF=valueF|fieldG=valueG|fieldH=valueH|recordType=C|id=3
```

Is there a way, though, to do this task using single `awk` command?

Comment: Could you please do post samples of expected output in your question to make it better, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - added the result of processing the sample

Comment: Thanks for edit, could you please do explain what is the logic of getting expected output more, thank you.

Comment: I had to sort the records according to the value of the `id` field (which doesn't have a fixed position), so I extracted said value by searching for a key, added it to the record, sorted the output and removed prepended identifier to get clean records; I've added my algorithm to the question, please check if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this `gnu-awk` code to to this in a single command:

```sh
awk -F'|' '{
   for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i ~ /^id=/) {
         a[gensub(/^id=/, "", 1, $i)] = $0
         break
      }
}
END {
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
   for (i in a)
      print a[i]
}' file

fieldD=valueD|recordType=B|id=1|fieldE=valueE
fieldA=valueA|fieldB=valueB|recordType=A|id=2|fieldC=valueC
fieldF=valueF|fieldG=valueG|fieldH=valueH|recordType=C|id=3
```

We are using `|` as field delimiter and when there is a column name starting with `id=` we store it in array `a` with index as text after `=` and value as the full record.

Using `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"` we sort array `a` using numerical value of index and then in for loop we print value part to get the sorted output.

Comment: Does the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` parameter affect all the arrays within current awk command?

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `sorted_in`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/(^|\|)id=([0-9]+)/,a) {
    ids2vals[a[2]] = $0
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for ( id in ids2vals ) {
        print ids2vals[id]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
fieldD=valueD|recordType=B|id=1|fieldE=valueE
fieldA=valueA|fieldB=valueB|recordType=A|id=2|fieldC=valueC
fieldF=valueF|fieldG=valueG|fieldH=valueH|recordType=C|id=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Perl: `perl -e 'print map { s/^.*? //; $_ } sort { $a <=> $b } map { ($id) = /id=(\d+)/; "$id $_" } <>' file`

Some explanation of the code I use:

```perl
print #print the resulting list of lines
    map {
        s/^.*? //;
        $_
    } #remove numeric id from start of line
    sort { $a <=> $b } #sort numerically
    map {
        ($id) = /id=(\d+)/;
        "$id $_"
    } # capture id and place it in start of line
    <> # read all lines from file
```

Or try `sed` and `sort`: `sed 's/^\(.*id=\([0-9][0-9]*\).*\)$/\2 \1/' file | sort -n | sed 's/^[^ ][^ ]* //'`

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples only, please try following(`awk` + `sort` + `cut`) solution, written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/id=[0-9]+/){
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)";"$0
}
' Input_file | sort -t'=' -k2n | cut -d';' -f2-
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/id=[0-9]+/){                  ##Using awk match function to match id= followed by digits.
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)";"$0  ##printing sub string of matched value followed by current line along with semi-colon in it.
}
' Input_file    |                       ##Mentioning Input_file here and passing awk output as a standard input to next command.
sort -t'=' -k2n |                       ##Sorting output with delimiter of = and by 2nd field then passing output to next command as an input.
cut -d';' -f2-                          ##Using cut command making delimiter as ; and printing everything from 2nd field onwards.
```